# how to set a version on dynamically created dll

Tags: c#, dll, reflection

I need some help with setting a version on a dynamically created dll.

I'm creating the dll using the CodeDomProvider and I can't set the version of the output assembly.

I've seen in some blogs that it can be done only if you set the compiler parameters to generate an executable and not in-memory.

my code is:

```
using System;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

namespace dynamicDll
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
            parameters.GenerateInMemory = true;
            parameters.GenerateExecutable = false;
            parameters.IncludeDebugInformation = true;
            parameters.OutputAssembly = "Dynamic.dll";
            var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                            .Where(a => !a.IsDynamic)
                            .Select(a => a.Location);
            parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.AddRange(assemblies.ToArray());

            CompilerResults cr = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp")
                .CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, @"          
namespace Dynamic
                    {
                        public class DynamicDllClass
                        {
                            public int X { get {return 7;}}
                        }
                    }");
            cr.CompiledAssembly.GetName().Version = new Version("1.0.0.0");
            var instance = cr.CompiledAssembly.CreateInstance("Dynamic.DynamicDllClass");
            int x = (int) instance.GetType().GetProperty("X").GetGetMethod().Invoke(instance, null);
            Debug.Assert(x==7);
            Debug.Assert(cr.CompiledAssembly.FullName.Contains("1.0.0.0"));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thank you [linuser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4445118/linuser)!

the following code is working great!

```
using System;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace dynamicDll
{
    class Programs
    {
        static void Mains(string[] args)
        {
            CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
            parameters.GenerateInMemory = true;
            parameters.GenerateExecutable = false;
            parameters.IncludeDebugInformation = true;
            parameters.OutputAssembly = "Dynamic.dll";
            var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                            .Where(a => !a.IsDynamic)
                            .Select(a => a.Location);
            parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.AddRange(assemblies.ToArray());
            var versionString = "1.0.0.0";

            CompilerResults cr = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp")
                .CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, @"
using System.Reflection;
[assembly: AssemblyVersion(" + "\"" + versionString + "\"" + @")]                    
namespace Dynamic
                    {
                        public class DynamicDllClass
                        {
                            public int X { get {return 7;}}
                        }
                    }");

            var instance = cr.CompiledAssembly.CreateInstance("Dynamic.DynamicDllClass");
            int x = (int) instance.GetType().GetProperty("X").GetGetMethod().Invoke(instance, null);
            Debug.Assert(x==7);
            Debug.Assert(cr.CompiledAssembly.FullName.Contains(versionString));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign it to your source code file using reflection attributes. The code provider will look for it, extract it and add the required metadata.

Decorate your source class as follows:

```
using System.Reflection;

[assembly: AssemblyVersion("2.1.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("2.1.0.0")]
public class Your_Class{}
```

Comment: I want to change the dynamic dll version, do you mean that I should add the Assembly version to the code text?